# Configuration of dropbox-nautilus package hangs while downloading dropbox binary

Tags: apt, dpkg, dropbox

While installing dropbox from the repositories, my laptop ran out of power, and so the system went into a broken state. When I rebooted, I tried two methods to set it right. One was

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

and

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Both were working fine, and they were downloading the dropbox package, but owing to my slow internet connection here, it's never getting completed, and is stuck at (at most) 47 %. A sample terminal-shot is

```
Setting up nautilus-dropbox (1.4.0-3)...
Dropbox is the easiest way to share and store your files online. Want to learn more? Head to http://www.dropbox.com/
Downloading Dropbox... 16%
```

So if this doesn't get completed the package will remain broken for ever, and I won't be able to install more software. So if there any way, I can rollback and then download dropbox from the site instead?

When I run `dpkg -l | grep -v ^ii`

```
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                                      Version                                   Architecture Description
+++-=========================================-=========================================-============-==============================================================================
rc  libavcodec53:i386                         6:0.8.5-0ubuntu0.12.10.1                  i386         Libav codec library
rc  libavutil51:i386                          6:0.8.5-0ubuntu0.12.10.1                  i386         Libav utility library
iF  nautilus-dropbox                          1.4.0-3                                   i386         Dropbox integration for Nautilus
```

Comment: Perhaps `sudo apt-get autoremove`, `sudo apt-get clean` and `sudo apt-get autoclean` will work. Please try all of these.

Comment: Please include in your question the output of `dpkg -l | grep -v ^ii`. This will list all packages not completely installed.

Comment: I'm apprehensive about these three commands, because the last time I used them, I could do nothing after that. I had to reinstall Ubuntu.

Comment: @EricCarvalho, here goes.
 `Libav codec library`, `Libav utility library`, `nautilus-dropbox`

Comment: @user42933 I think problem is nautilus-dropbox. This is not the full output spit by dpkg. Don't insert this in the comment area, please copy all the text from terminal, edit your QUESTION and include the text there.

Comment: @EricCarvalho done.

Comment: Whenever I execute sudo apt-get install nautilus-dropbox, the download of Dropbox is VERY slow.  My guess is that Dropbox is limiting the bandwidth used when the clent is installed using nautilus-dropbox (as opposed to downloading the deb package directly), or there is a bug in the nautilus-dropbox installer that causes it to download very slowly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's fool nautilus-dropbox configuration scripts.

Backup some files:

```
sudo cp -a /var/lib/dpkg/info/nautilus-dropbox.postinst /var/lib/dpkg/info/nautilus-dropbox.postinst.bkp
sudo cp -a /var/lib/dpkg/info/nautilus-dropbox.prerm /var/lib/dpkg/info/nautilus-dropbox.prerm.bkp
```

Write new empty postinst and prerm scripts:

```
echo '#!/bin/sh' | sudo tee /var/lib/dpkg/info/nautilus-dropbox.postinst
echo 'exit 0' | sudo tee -a /var/lib/dpkg/info/nautilus-dropbox.postinst
sudo cp -a /var/lib/dpkg/info/nautilus-dropbox.postinst /var/lib/dpkg/info/nautilus-dropbox.prerm
```

Now you should be able to remove nautilus-dropbox:

```
sudo apt-get purge nautilus-dropbox
```

Comment: I can't. 

`E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.`

Comment: In fact `autoclean` or `autoremove` also doesn't work because of the same reason.

Comment: Answer updated.

Answer (score -1):

I just had the same problem and could fix it by running:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

and canceling it with CTRL+C. Then

```
sudo apt-get purge nautilus-dropbox
```

ran just fine.